# deg2km command does not calculate distance between two points in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to calculate distance between two geographical coordinates and I want to convert geographical coordinates to the km. Therefore I used `deg2km` function. However, I realise that it is not convert points properly.

For instance, I used these two points.

```
p_x=[5; 10];        %degree
p_y=[8; 16];        %degree
pos_y=deg2km(p_y,6378);
pos_x=deg2km(p_x,6378);
```

It returns as:

```
pos_x= [556.58549846099 1113.17099692198]   
pos_y= [890.536797537587 1781.07359507517]
```

When I calculate distance ( `sqrt((556.5-1113.2)^2+(890.5368-1781.1)^2)` ) between these points I obtained distance as : **1050.2464**

However I checked it google map and also other websites it should be **1042** km.

Do you have any suggestion to calculate distance and also points as kilometers properly?

Thanks in advance!

**edited as :**

I've points(deg)and I need to convert them km and calculate distance between points.

```
LAT=[41.000173;41.010134]*pi/180; 
LON=[28.995882;28.995584]*pi/180;
```

I used this code to calculate distance.  It calculates properly. 
But I can not convert my points to kilometers.

```
LAT=[41.000173;41.010134]*pi/180; 
LON=[28.995882;28.995584]*pi/180;

 R=6378; %km

 for i=1:length(LAT)-1 

psi(i,1) = atan2( sin (LON(i+1)-LON(i)) * cos (LAT(i+1)) , cos (LAT(i)) *sin (LAT(i+1)) - sin (LAT(i)) * cos (LAT(i+1)) * cos (LON(i+1)-LON(i)) );

a=(sin((LAT(i+1)-LAT(i))/2))^2+cos(LAT(i))*cos(LAT(i+1))*(sin((LON(i+1)-LON(i))/2))^2;

c=2*atan2(sqrt(a),sqrt(1-a)); 

d(i,1)=R*c; 

end
```

Comment: And what answer do you get if you omit the Earth radius in your calls to `deg2km` ?

Comment: If I run this code 
pos_y=deg2km(p_y);

pos_x=deg2km(p_x);  
like that results that I obtained is : 1048.9687km 
It is still different than google map or other websites.

Comment: Your reference calculation measures along a straight line. Matlab and Google measure along the surface. For matlab the earth is a sphere. Websites like Google probably account for the different radius at the pole and equator.

Comment: So do you have any suggestion to match this two results? I could not be sure my code is correct or not.

Comment: Neither of the 3 versions is wrong, but each calculates something else. What do you need?

Comment: I've points(deg)and I need to convert them km and calculate distance between points. 
LAT=[41.000173;41.010134]*pi/180;
LON=[28.995882;28.995584]*pi/180; 
I used this code to calculate distance. It calculates properly. But I can not convert my points to kilometers. 
R=6378; %km
for i=1:length(LAT)-1
psi(i,1) = atan2( sin (LON(i+1)-LON(i)) * cos (LAT(i+1)) , cos (LAT(i)) *sin (LAT(i+1)) - sin (LAT(i)) * cos (LAT(i+1)) * cos (LON(i+1)-LON(i)) );

a=(sin((LAT(i+1)-LAT(i))/2))^2+cos(LAT(i))*cos(LAT(i+1))*(sin((LON(i+1)-LON(i))/2))^2;
c=2*atan2(sqrt(a),sqrt(1-a));
d(i,1)=R*c;
end

Comment: That code in the comments is unreadable. Please edit your question and complete it.

Comment: sorry, edited. @Daniel

Comment: Did you ever run your code? I get an invalid expression because an operator is missing.

Comment: @daniel can you check it please?