# Problem to converting km to geographical coordinates

Tags: matlab

I have some questions about converting kilometers to geographical coordinates.
As you can see figure attached, the left one is trajectory interms of kilometers. I entered geographical coordinates and calculate trajectory as kilometers. For my calculations I need to convert degrees to kilometers. I used this code:

```
LAT=[41.030503; 41.048334; 41.071551   ]*pi/180;
LON=[28.999000; 29.037494; 29.052138   ]*pi/180;
for i=1:length(LAT)-1
psi_coordinate(i,1) = atan2( sin (LON(i+1)-LON(i)) * cos (LAT(i+1)) , cos (LAT(i)) *sin (LAT(i+1)) - sin (LAT(i)) * cos (LAT(i+1)) * cos (LON(i+1)-LON(i)) );

a=(sin((LAT(i+1)-LAT(i))/2))^2+cos(LAT(i))*cos(LAT(i+1))*(sin((LON(i+1)-LON(i))/2))^2;
c=2*atan2(sqrt(a),sqrt(1-a));
d(i,1)=R*c;

pos_x(i+1,1)=pos_x(i,1)+d(i,1)*cos(psi_coordinate(i,1));   %convert to kilometer
pos_y(i+1,1)=pos_y(i,1)+d(i,1)*sin(psi_coordinate(i,1));   %convert to kilometer
distance_h(i,1)=sqrt(((LAT(i+1)-LAT(i))^2)+((LON(i+1)-LON(i))^2))*1000 ;    %kilometer

end
distance=sum(d);
pos_x=pos_x*1000;   %convert to meter
pos_y=pos_y*1000;   %convert to meter
```

pos_x and pos_y are ploted as circle at the figure (left).

After I calculate ship trajectory, I need to convert them degrees again. 
If I use "km2deg" command I obtained my coordinates as given figure (right) and the code that I used is:

```
ydeg=LON(1)*180/pi+km2deg(y/1000);
xdeg=LAT(1)*180/pi+km2deg(x/1000);
```

But as you can see the blue line (ship trajectory) is not close to the desired path as figure given left. Normally it should be the same trend for these two plot. Because all I do is here is just converting the units. I guess I have some troubles to used "km2deg" command.

Do you have any suggestions to convert my points correctly from km to deg?

[image]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59953933/8239061

Comment: Yes @SecretAgentMan but I could not find a solution for both of them.

Comment: No worries!  This helps volunteers understand the context behind the question since they are related.  (Related ≠ Duplicate)

Comment: You can reproject your lon/lat coordinate to another coordinate system where the unit are in meter. For example from [EPSG 4326](https://epsg.io/4326) to [EPSG 5637](https://epsg.io/5637)

Comment: @obchardon sorry, but I did not understand how can I use them?

Comment: Hmmm... you can use the [projfwd](https://mathworks.com/help/map/ref/projfwd.htm) function, but it require the mapping toolbox, I will check if there is another option.

Comment: Thanks! @obchardon You can find my x and y values that I try to convert degrees in this file : (+ they are given as meter at the attached file)
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a5124e9a367275a76c2bf5fd9ea99fa320200203180815/d6400d6dd9f44f15cfcb9958d2aeafce20200203180815/48d24c

Comment: Any sugesstions??

Comment: As a temporary solution, I solve this issue scaling blue line at left figure according to ratio between two red lines.